# port 7199 , 36204 cassandra whom should it be open for?

Tags: cassandra, jmx, datastax, ports

I know 7199 is used for "monitoring JMX" who is monitoring it opscenter or nodetool or both ?
in this case is it enough that ports is open only for the peers . Also I'm seeing port 36204 is being listened on by cassandra . its not mentioned in documentation of cassandra datastax. whats this port for?

Comment: Can you give an example from `netstat -lnt` from your node and show port `36204` in your original question? Thanks

Comment: what version are you using?

Comment: 3.7 cassandra version community

Comment: strange now its not running . i don't know if it stopped . cause i'm sure it was running from the service cassandra itself .